# Testing REST api with postman

Tags: api-testing, rest-api

I am very new to this, so I am approaching it like I would test a sign up form for instance. 
I have a Rest interface exposed for testing operations:
Getting all users, getting users by id, searching users by email, inserting users.
I covered all the happy flow options, I covered searching for non-existing user, getting user by non-existing id, inserting 'empty' user.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear on your question are you more interested in information about strategy for testing REST APIs or specifically in how to use Postman or one of its features?

Comment: For now I am handling Postman well, it's the strategy I'm interested in :)

Answer (score 3):

**It depends**

Some things you may want to consider:

- **Badly formed input** - how does the API handle badly formed input? Can you send it something from the [Big List of Naughty Strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings) and get back data you didn't expect?
- **Security** - If the API uses an auth header, can you access anything useful without one? If something else is used, can you bypass it with your tests?
- **Flow** - can you create a user then do something with that user's credentials? Can you create an empty user then do something with those credentials?

Ultimately, what you can test comes down to a combination of what tests you can imagine, and how much time you have to create and run tests.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did test some badly formed input, but I will continue, this comment is very helpful!